# Undo functionality does not exist in Hubspot after you save?

Tags: inline-editing, hubspot

Are there any other IDE's you can use to develop an Html email for Hubspot?

Once I preview the email I am developing in their IDE and go back to edit,

I can not undo anything. IMO that is horrible for Development or any type

of editing. Any thoughts or suggestions on how to get around this archaic

experience?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any IDE you'd like and connect to HubSpot via FTP. I personally use Sublime Text and utilize the [Sublime SFTP](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) plugin to connect via FTP.

https://designers.hubspot.com/docs/tools/hubspot-ftp

Comment: How does that solving being able to preview a page if I am using their liquid markup? IE: {% widget_attribute "html" %}
              <a href="{{ buttonLink }}">{{ buttonText }}</a>
                {% end_widget_attribute %}